# AES Encryption Golang and Python

Tags: python, encryption, go, cryptography, aes

I am working on a fun side project for myself. A golang server and a python client. I want data transmitted to be encrypted but cant seem to get the two encryption schemes working together. I am a novice when it comes to encryption so please explain like you are talking to a toddler.

Here is my golang encryption functions:

```
import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "fmt"
)
func Encrypt(key, text []byte) (ciphertext []byte, err error) {
    var block cipher.Block
    if block, err = aes.NewCipher(key); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ciphertext = make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(string(text)))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    fmt.Println(aes.BlockSize)
    if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        return
    }
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], text)
    return
}

func Decrypt(key, ciphertext []byte) (plaintext []byte, err error) {
    var block cipher.Block
    if block, err = aes.NewCipher(key); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        err = errors.New("ciphertext too short")
        return
    }
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:]
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
    cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext, ciphertext)
    plaintext = ciphertext
    return
}
```

and here is my Python implementation:

```
 class AESCipher:
    def __init__( self, key ):
        self.key = key
        print "INIT KEY" + hexlify(self.key)
    def encrypt( self, raw ):
        print "RAW STRING: " + hexlify(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
        cipher = AES.new( self.key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv )
        r = ( iv + cipher.encrypt( raw ) )
        print "ECRYPTED STRING: " + hexlify(r)
        return r

    def decrypt( self, enc ):
        enc = (enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
        x=(cipher.decrypt( enc ))
        print "DECRYPTED STRING: " + hexlify(x)
        return x
```

i cant quite figure out the output of my python functions either. My Go routines are working perfectly. But i want to be able to encrypt in Go an decrypt in python and vice versa.

Sample Output from Python:

```
INIT KEY61736466617364666173646661736466
RAW STRING: 54657374206d657373616765
ECRYPTED STRING: dfee33dd40c32fbaf9aac73ac4e0a5a9fc7bd2947d29005dd8d8e21a
dfee33dd40c32fbaf9aac73ac4e0a5a9fc7bd2947d29005dd8d8e21a
DECRYPTED STRING: 77d899b990d2d3172a3229b1b69c6f2554657374206d657373616765
77d899b990d2d3172a3229b1b69c6f2554657374206d657373616765
wØ™¹�ÒÓ*2)±¶œo%Test message
```

As you can see the message is decrypted but ends up at the end of the string?

**EDIT:**
Sample output decrypting from GO.
If i try and decrypt with GO the below (generated with Python)

```
ECRYPTED STRING: (Test Message) 7af474bc4c8ea9579d83a3353f83a0c2844f8efb019c82618ea0b478
```

I get

```
Decrypted Payload: 54 4E 57 9B 90 F8 D6 CD 12 59 0B B1
Decrypted Payload: TNW�����Y�
```

The strange part is the first character is always correct

here are both full projects:

[Github](https://github.com/engineerbeard)

Comment: I strongly recommend you use https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/secretbox and https://pynacl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ (for Python) if you need to encrypt messages.

Answer (score 5):

Python uses 8-bit segments while Go uses 128-bit segments so the reason the first character works but the following ones don't is because each segment depends on the previous and thus a different segment size breaks the chain.

I made these URL safe (non-padded base64 encoding) encrypt/decrypt functions for Python to optionally encrypt the same way Go does (when you specify `block_segments=True`).

```
def decrypt(key, value, block_segments=False):
    # The base64 library fails if value is Unicode. Luckily, base64 is ASCII-safe.
    value = str(value)
    # We add back the padding ("=") here so that the decode won't fail.
    value = base64.b64decode(value + '=' * (4 - len(value) % 4), '-_')
    iv, value = value[:AES.block_size], value[AES.block_size:]
    if block_segments:
        # Python uses 8-bit segments by default for legacy reasons. In order to support
        # languages that encrypt using 128-bit segments, without having to use data with
        # a length divisible by 16, we need to pad and truncate the values.
        remainder = len(value) % 16
        padded_value = value + '\0' * (16 - remainder) if remainder else value
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
        # Return the decrypted string with the padding removed.
        return cipher.decrypt(padded_value)[:len(value)]
    return AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).decrypt(value)


def encrypt(key, value, block_segments=False):
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    if block_segments:
        # See comment in decrypt for information.
        remainder = len(value) % 16
        padded_value = value + '\0' * (16 - remainder) if remainder else value
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
        value = cipher.encrypt(padded_value)[:len(value)]
    else:
        value = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).encrypt(value)
    # The returned value has its padding stripped to avoid query string issues.
    return base64.b64encode(iv + value, '-_').rstrip('=')
```

Note that **for secure message passing** you want additional security features, such as a nonce to prevent against replay attacks.

Here are the Go equivalent functions:

```
func Decrypt(key []byte, encrypted string) ([]byte, error) {
    ciphertext, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(encrypted)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        return nil, errors.New("ciphertext too short")
    }
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:]
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
    cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext, ciphertext)
    return ciphertext, nil
}

func Encrypt(key, data []byte) (string, error) {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(data))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], data)
    return base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext), nil
}
```

Comment: For me it needs a little modification and it works like a charm. Here's how: modify line 12 on decrypt() to this: ```padded_value = value + b'\0' * (16 - remainder) if remainder else value``` and modify the last line on encrypt() to ```return base64.b64encode(iv + value, b'-_').rstrip(b'=')```

Comment: been stuck on this for a few days, Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to slice off the IV during decryption in Python. Change

```
x=(cipher.decrypt( enc ))
```

to

```
x = cipher.decrypt( enc[16:] )
```

or to

```
x = cipher.decrypt( enc )[16:]
```

Comment: These two suggestions are equivalent for modes like CFB (with full block shift register) and CBC, but will not work for modes like CTR. In that case, go with the first one.

Comment: thanks this helped with the python part, i made an edit above for decrypting with Go. Thanks!